# How remainder opearator works in c

Tags: c

```
I can understand 3%2 gives 1.
As 2*1+1 so 1 is remainder.     

Why -3%2 gives -1, 3%-2 gives 1 and -3%-2 gives -1. Lot of confusion.
```

Can somebody explain/clarify please. Tried to find out duplicate ones but couldn't find similar to this.

Not sure if its a very silly question ;-)

Comment: Not a silly question but a somewhat frequently asked one. The answer depends on version of the C standard. See the most upvoted answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%` operator in C is not the modulo operator but the remainder operator.

Modulo and remainder operators differ with respect to negative values.

With a remainder operator, the sign of the result is the same as the sign of the dividend while with a modulo operator the sign of the result is the same as the divisor.

C defines the % operation for a % b as:

```
a == (a / b * b) + a % b
```

with / the integer division with truncation towards 0. That's the truncation that is done towards 0 (and not towards negative inifinity) that defines the % as a remainder operator rather than a modulo operator.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the modulo and division should satisfy the equation

`b * (a/b) + a%b == a`

For positive numbers, it is obvious that this means that `a%b` must be a positive number. But if `a/b` is negative, then the result is rounded towards zero.

So take for instance `a = -3, b = 2`. We know that `a/b = -1.50`, which rounded towards zero becomes `a/b == -1`. From the equation above, we have that `b * (-1) + a%b == a`. If we insert a and b, we get `-2 + a%b == -3`, and we see that a%b must be `-1`.

Similarly you can for other cases.